# Cannot use MatchMode with variable of type double

Tags: spring, hibernate, datatables, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I am implementing `server-side` filtering of `dataTable`. In the service which implements the filtering I want to test if the `search` criteria is a `number` ; if so then I implement the filtering based on the bean attribute of type `double` ( salary ) , otherwise I make the filtering based on the bean attribute of type String ( username ) :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<User> list(int start, int length, String search) {
    Criteria criteres = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    if (!search.equals("")) {
        if (NumberUtils.isNumber(search))
            criteres.add(Restrictions.like("salary", Double.parseDouble(search)));
        else
            criteres.add(Restrictions.like("username", search, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    }
    criteres.setFirstResult(start);
    criteres.setMaxResults(length);
    criteres.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> listUser = (List<User>) criteres.list();
    return listUser;
}
```

The problem is that if I write :

```
if (!search.equals("")) {
    if (NumberUtils.isNumber(search))
        criteres.add(Restrictions.like("salary", String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(search)), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    else
        criteres.add(Restrictions.like("username", search, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
}
```

then I got alert error : `DataTables warning: table id=t_list - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

So how to make possible to make a "**like**" condition on the `double` variable ?

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible, even if your sgbd can do it .I tried it with Integer without success

Comment: There is a simple solution : use HQL or native query. If you realy want to use criteria API I think the only way is to implements you own criterion so you can control the sql output un the toSqlString method

Comment: what about `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` in that case ? how to call them ? are there equivalents of them with `Query` ?

Comment: setFirstResult and setMaxResults does not change you can still call it on the Criteria or Query Object